# Spring Circular Reference

Tags: java, spring, circular-reference

As far as I know, Spring resolves circular reference issue by exposing an `ObjectFactory` of each bean currently in creation.

The problem I feel confused is : Why not instantiate each bean at first, and then populate autowire field using `Field.set(obj,val)`, why bother to make it so complicated using cache and object factory.

Comment: Because not everyone uses field injection...

Comment: In other words; some are using constructor injection. Or setters have side effects, null checks etc..

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency resolution process](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-dependency-resolution)

> Circular dependencies
>
> If you use predominantly constructor injection, it is possible to
>   create an unresolvable circular dependency scenario.
>
> For example: Class A requires an instance of class B through
>   constructor injection, and class B requires an instance of class A
>   through constructor injection. If you configure beans for classes A
>   and B to be injected into each other, the Spring IoC container detects
>   this circular reference at runtime, and throws a
>   BeanCurrentlyInCreationException.
>
> One possible solution is to edit the source code of some classes to be
>   configured by setters rather than constructors. Alternatively, avoid
>   constructor injection and use setter injection only. In other words,
>   although it is not recommended, you can configure circular
>   dependencies with setter injection.
>
> Unlike the typical case (with no circular dependencies), a circular
>   dependency between bean A and bean B forces one of the beans to be
>   injected into the other prior to being fully initialized itself (a
>   classic chicken/egg scenario).